# Picture in resources folder doesn't exist when I eject my USB flashdisk

Tags: iphone, xcode

I placed pictures from my USB flash disk to the resources folder in Xcode, everything is ok, but when I eject my flash, Xcode didn't recognize my picture and it became red, help please.

Comment: Have you chosen to "copy" the resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the picture into your project folder, otherwise XCode only creates a reference to the file. The easiest way to do that is to delete the file from your resources folder, and then redrag it in from your flash disk. When the box pops up to import it, make sure the checkbox in the upper corner is selected to copy the files into your project folder.

Comment: the checkbox you talking about is this with the message : copy items into destinations group's folder(if needed) ??

Comment: Absolutely. Yes. I always select this box. Can't think of a time I didn't want to have something in the projects folders.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check `Copy items into destination group's folder`, else XCode will only reference it. If checked it does copy your files to the project folder.